# Revert database context to previous state EF Core 7

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a console app to migrate a large number of data from Sharepoint to a SQL Server database.

I have a database context and, inside if, a for loop of some items from Sharepoint. For every item I have a transaction so the final code is something like this:

```
using (ExampleContext db = new ExampleContext())
{
    List<Item> sharepointItems = Installer_Service.SharepointItems();     
    // this has some parameters but it's irrelevant
    for (int d = 0; d < sharepointItems.Count; d++)
    { 
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                // the whole code
                db.SaveChanges();
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that `sharepointItems.Count = 4`, I start to loop. The first item goes smoothly.

The second item catches with some exception. With "continue" I can go on to the third item of the loop. When I try to save the third item, though, I still have the context with the exception of the previous item so the third one also catches, even if there's nothing wrong with it.

I'm looping a list that could contain a million items so opening a context for each one would kill the database (SQL Server).

Is there a way to do something like the `tran.Rollback` but with the context? Saving the current context state at the beginning of every loop and then restore it in case it catches?

Comment: The code is completely wrong. EF is misused in two critical ways. First of all, EF (and any ORM) isn't an ETL tool and definitely not meant to bulk import 10K rows, much less 1M rows. It's like using a scalpel when you actually want a dump truck. The class that performs bulk imports is SqlBulkCopy. Second, you don't reset DbContexts nor do you use explicit transactions. You don't call SaveChanges in loops.

Comment: A DbContext is neither a connection nor a database, it's a Unit of Work. It keeps track of all pending changes in a *specific business use case*. It's meant to live only as long as the "business transaction" is active. It doesn't even open a connection until you load or save stuff. When `SaveChanges` is called **ALL** changes are persisted in a single internal database transaction. If want to discard the changes, dispose it. Never reuse it

Comment: `With "continue" i can go on to the third item` no you can't. The application got an exception because it did something invalid

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I like this first comment. I think maybe this is why EF gets a bad wrap because it is not performant for large database transactions and executions? It is meant simply as a CRUD simplizer but beyond that is abuse of the ORM?